# Is there an ignore command for git like there is for svn?

Tags: git, gitignore, ignore

I am a new user to `git` and I am starting a new project. I have a bunch of dot files that I would like to ignore. Is there an ignore command for `git` like there is for `svn`?

Comment: Good alternative to gitignore: **git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>** , thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16442091/2162226

Answer (score 143, accepted):

There is no special `git ignore` command.

Edit a `.gitignore` file located in the appropriate place within the working copy. You should then add this `.gitignore` and commit it. Everyone who clones that repo will than have those files ignored.

Note that only file names starting with `/` will be relative to the directory `.gitignore` resides in. Everything else will match files in whatever subdirectory.

You can also edit `.git/info/exclude` to ignore specific files just in that one working copy. The `.git/info/exclude` file will not be committed, and will thus only apply locally in this one working copy.

You can also set up a global file with patterns to ignore with `git config --global core.excludesfile`. This will locally apply to all git working copies on the same user's account.

Run `git help gitignore` and read the text for the details.

Comment: Not having a simple ignore command seems like such an oversight on the part of the git team.

Comment: @jcollum At first glance it does, but the simplicity of aliasing a command to add new ones AND the complexity of creating one and working through all the edge cases/gotchas/potential issues of editing a text file also makes sense to leave it to the user. I feel conflicted because I both agree and disagree with you.

Answer (score 105):

A very useful [git ignore](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md#git-ignore) command comes with the awesome [tj/git-extras](https://github.com/tj/git-extras).

Here are a few usage examples:

#### List all currently ignored patterns

```
git ignore
```

#### Add a pattern

```
git ignore "*.log"
```

#### Add one of the templates from [gitignore.io](https://gitignore.io)

```
git ignore-io -a rails
```

[git-extras](https://github.com/tj/git-extras) provides many more useful commands. Definitely worth trying out.

Comment: So if I use git ignore "index.html" it will ignore this file?

Comment: Is the -t command still applicable?  When I run it, it just adds the -t and whatever template I try to add into the git ignore file

Answer (score 54):

On Linux/Unix, you can append files to the .gitignore file with the `echo` command. For example if you want to ignore all `.svn` folders, run this from the root of the project:

```
echo .svn/ >> .gitignore
```

Comment: I found out this tweet using that syntax https://twitter.com/noodl_io/status/669904872704253953

Comment: In Git Bash on Windows, I needed to add a preceding `/` and trailing '\' (to create a new line), such as `echo /nbproject/project.properties\ >> .gitignore` and `echo /nbproject/project.xml\ >> .gitignore`.

Comment: That forward slash `/` character in the end is of paramount importance. Without it, the new rule gets appended to the last entry already existing in the `.gitignore` file in place of getting created as a new entry at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 15):

You have two ways of ignoring files:

- `.gitignore` in any folder will ignore the files as specified in the file for that folder. Using wildcards is possible.
- `.git/info/exclude` holds the global ignore pattern, similar to the `global-ignores` in subversions configuration file.

Comment: Note that patterns in `.gitignore` file which do not contain '/' are matched **recursively** (i.e. also in all subdirectories of the directory the `.gitignore` file is in), contrary to the case of `svn:ignore` directory properties in Subversion.

Answer (score 4):

Create a file named .gitignore on the root of your repository. In this file you put the relative path to each file you wish to ignore in a single line. You can use the `*` wildcard.

Answer (score 3):

It's useful to define a complete *.gitignore* file for your project. The reward is safe use of the convenient `--all` or `-a` flag to commands like `add` and `commit`.

Also, consider defining a global *~/.gitignore* file for commonly ignored patterns such as `*~`, which covers temporary files created by Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Using the answers already provided, you can roll your own `git ignore` command using an [alias](http://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases). Either add this to your ~/.gitconfig file:

```
ignore = !sh -c 'echo $1 >> .gitignore' -
```

Or run this command from the (*nix) shell of your choice:

```
git config --global alias.ignore '!sh -c "echo $1 >> .gitignore" -'
```

You can likewise create a `git exclude` command by replacing `ignore` with `exclude` and `.gitignore` with `.git/info/exclude` in the above.

(If you don't already understand the difference between these two files having read the answers here, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097368/git-ignore-vs-exclude-vs-assume-unchanged).)

Comment: The answer here expands $1 correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21884533/1465227

Answer (score 2):

You have to install git-extras for this. You can install it in Ubuntu using apt-get,

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-extras
```

Then you can use the git ignore command.

```
$ git ignore file_name
```

Comment: On Mac, if you have Homebrew installed, you can run `brew install git-extras`.

Answer (score 2):

for names not present in the working copy or repo:

```
echo /globpattern >> .gitignore
```

or for an existing file (sh type command line):

```
echo /$(ls -1 file) >> .gitignore   # I use tab completion to select the file to be ignored  
git rm -r --cached file             # if already checked in, deletes it on next commit
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Joe Blau's gitignore.io

Either through the web interfase https://www.gitignore.io/

Or by installing the CLI tool, it's very easy an fast, just type the following on your terminal:

Linux:
`echo "function gi() { curl -L -s https://www.gitignore.io/api/\$@ ;}" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`

OSX:
`echo "function gi() { curl -L -s https://www.gitignore.io/api/\$@ ;}" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`

And then you can just type `gi` followd by the all the platform/environment elements you need gitignore criteria for.

**Example!**
Lets say you're working on a node project that includes grunt and you're using webstorm on linux, then you may want to type:
`gi linux,webstorm,node,grunt > .gitignore` ( to make a brand new file)
or
`gi linux,webstorm,node,grunt >> .gitignore` ( to append/add the new rules to an existing file)

bam, you're good to go