# GitHub pages - staging site

Tags: github-pages

I have a GitHub pages site.  I would like to implement some staging on a separate branch.

So basically, I would like to host the staging branch on another DNS, built by GitHub pages.

Is there a way to do that without doing the build locally?

I've seen comments here and there referring to a gh-pages branch but haven't found any documentation around that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating staging and production versions of a site on Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911091/creating-staging-and-production-versions-of-a-site-on-github-pages)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing staging in a separate branch, I do it in a separate GitHub repo.

Keeping a separate branch with separate staging configs, staging `CNAME` and DNS files, and staging-specific features is a hassle within the same repo. Separate repos is a simpler solution since it maintains the mental model that development and staging are different environments.

So there's 2 GitHub repos: a main and a staging repo. GitHub Pages settings allows for separate DNS settings. Since I have a custom domain, the main repo is set to `www.customDomain.com` and staging repo is set to `staging.customDomain.com`.

Here's my setup using `Main` and `Staging` repo names. `Staging` is set as a remote for `Main`, and `Staging` is an exact copy of `Main` (besides configs, `CNAME`, staging-specific features, etc...).

GitHub Pages builds the site using the `master` branch in `Main`. I use a `dev` branch in `Main` to hold the new code and features. Development work is done in feature branches that branch off of `dev` and are merged back into `dev`. When I want to test the feature in `Staging`, I go to `Staging` and pull in the latest version of the `Main:dev` branch. After I'm done testing in `Staging`, then I'll pull `Main:dev` into `Main:master`.

Here's a diagram if that helps you understand the setup. Hopefully this answers your question.

```
 Main        Staging
  |   |       |
  |   |       |
  |\  |       |
  | \ |       |
  |  \|       |
  |   |       |
  |   |       |
  |   |\      |
  |   | \     |
  |   |  \    |
  |   |   \   |
  |   |    \  |
  |   |     \ |
  |   |      \|
  |   |       |
  |   |       |
  |   |      /|
  |   |     / |
  |   |    /  |
  |   |   /   |
  |   |  /    |
  |   | /     |
  |   |/      |
  |   |      Staging:master
  |   |\
  |   | \
  |   |  \
  |   |   |
  |   |   |
  |   |  /feature
  |   | /
  |   |/
  |   |
  |  /dev
  | /
  |/ 
  |
Main:master
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer DC!

I guess the follow up question is "how do you get GitHub Pages to build another repo / branch"?  My understanding is that it can only build <user name>.github.io...

Comment: Any repo can use GitHub Pages. I have my main repo named `UserName.github.io` and my staging repo named `Staging`. Both are being built from the `master` branch within that repo.

Answer (score 0):

My answer only applies since you said you're using a separate DNS AND have your own hosting service (I'm using Hostinger).

AFAIK, Without using external DNS the only way to maintain multiple environments (dev, staing, etc..) is to keep separate repos, and maybe naming them with env name suffixes. I don't like this approach, but I think it's a matter of preference rather than performance \ maintainability.

Here's how I did it:

1. As a convention, the GitHub page domain is my "testing" stage, and the hosted domain is my "production" stage.
2. For `testing`, setting a GitHub Action workflow triggered by a push to branch `dev`. That workflow's output [deploying to branch](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/push-git-subdirectory-as-branch) `gh-pages`, following the GitHub Pages convention. Remember to set your `index.html`'s `basehref` to match your repo name.
3. For `production`, clone the above workflow. Set the trigger event to pushes from `master`. Next, create a third output branch, I called it `domain`. Finally, i'm using my hosting service's "auto deployment" ability, which is just a web hook they provided that triggers a copy files from GitHub to the hosting service's own storage. Under the hood, it's just a workflow step that fires a `curl` command to `webhooks.hostinger.com/deploy/{some-random-guid}`

Good Luck :)