# Echos in gitconfig aliases echoing the entire list of command line arguments when only one expected

Tags: git, git-config, git-alias

For a long time, I had the following alias in my aliases file:

```
ignore=!([ ! -e .gitignore ] && touch .gitignore) | echo $1 >>.gitignore
```

It wasn't original to me, and if you search for it, you'll see it a lot of places.  Recently, however, I've started having a weird problem with the alias.  Anything I ignore gets placed twice in the .gitignore file and on the same line (with a space only).

I did a bit of debugging and found that what is really happening is that the call to `echo $1` is echoing `$1` as you'd expect, but also echoing the entire string of arguments to the alias.

To test this, I made a new alias:

```
eo = !echo $1

> git eo test
test test    

> git eo test0 test1
test0 test0 test1
```

That last line is the most interesting because it clearly shows that the echo call is getting the entire set of arguments tacked on to it while `$1` is getting evaluated correctly.  In fact, if I mess with things and change `$1` to `$9` (and don't fill `$9`), I get:

```
> git eo test0 test1
test0 test1
```

I have confirmed that this happens on Git versions 1.8.5 to 1.9.0 and I have confirmed that it DOES NOT happen in Git version 1.7.1; unfortunately, I am unable to test between 1.7.1 and 1.8.5.

Does anyone have any insight to what is going on here?  It breaks a few of my aliases...

Answer (score 3):

I think the expansion isn't what you expect.  Let's start with your alias:

```
eo = !echo $1
```

I believe `git eo test` is being expanded to:

```
echo $1 test
```

Which is then expanded to:

```
echo test test
```

The typical way git looks at the alias is to say when I say "eo", I want you to run "echo $1" and pass all arguments to that command.  That allows you to do things like

```
[alias]
k = !gitk
```

And still be able to pass arguments to `git k`.  If you want this to behave differently, you should pass it through a shell invocation like this:

```
[alias]
eo = !sh -c 'echo $1' -
```

Then you'll get the expected result.

I think for your ignore alias, you want something like

```
[alias]
ignore = !sh -c 'echo "$1" >> .gitignore' -
```

Note: you don't need to touch the file for `>>` to work, and in your original alias you probably meant to use `;` instead of piping the output of touch into echo.

Comment: `ignore = ! >>.gitignore echo` would probably also work (and allow you to add multiple files at once into your ignore file)