# git except a sub directory and it's files of a ignored directory

Tags: git

i use git to manage my sources,i have some file in bellow paths:

```
Debug/a.dll
Debug/b.exe
Debug/c.png
Debug/Pic/a.png
Debug/Pic/b.bmp
Debug/Pic/c.dll
```

I want to ignore those files:

```
Debug/a.dll
Debug/b.exe
Debug/c.png
```

But to excelude those files from ignore:

```
Debug/Pic/a.png
Debug/Pic/b.bmp
Debug/Pic/a.dll
```

Comment: If you want to understand why codeWizard's answer (which was false initially, before he added the missing element from my answer) work, see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30606460/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git use the `.gitignore` to ignore or to track files in ignored paths.

In your case you need to do add this to your `.gitignore` file in your project root directory. Create the file is it does not exist

```
#List of files to ignore
Debug/*

#List of files to exclude from the ignored pattern above
!Debug/Pic
!Debug/Pic/*
```

#### What is in content of this sample `.gitignore`

`Debug/*` - This will ignore all the files under the Debug folder
`!Debug/Pic/*` - The **`!`** is a special character in this case telling git to **exclude** the given pattern from the ignored paths.

**In other words:**
We "told" git to ignore all the files under the `Debug` folder but to include all the files under the `Debug/Pic/` folder.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, with exclusion in `gitignore`, the rule to remember is:

> **[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded (`*`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)**
>   (`*`: unless certain conditions are met in git 2.?, see below)

Since `Debug/*` would ignore the folder `Debug/Pic/`, trying to exclude the content of that folder would not work (`!Debug/Pic/*`) with git 2.6 or less.

You need to exclude the folder first. Then its content.

```
Debug/*
!Debug/Pic/
!Debug/Pic/*
```

---

Note that with git 2.9.x/2.10 (mid 2016?), it might be possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded [if there is no wildcard in the path re-included](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d589a67eceacd1cc171bbe94906ca7c9a0edd8c5#diff-7fea460d44f92f185e7add8aa5620305R144).

[Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds) is trying to add this feature:

- [commit 506d8f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/506d8f1b394917c345965fc1762afa66678870c1) for git v2.7.0, reverted in [commit 76b620d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76b620d8166bf4cc7cadbc61f9927799ceea9162) git v2.8.0-rc0
- [commit 5e57f9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e57f9c3dfe7dd44a1b56bb5b3327d7a1356ec7c) git v2.8.0-rc0,... reverted(!) in [commit 5cee3493](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415) git 2.8.0-rc4.

So in git 2.9+, in order to re-include the the folder `Debug/Pic/`, you can do:

```
/Debug
!Debug/Pic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the subdirectory first, then ignore the containing directory:

```
git add Debug/Pic
git ignore Debug
```

This will have the side effect of not showing the addition of new files to Debug/Pic, but you can just add them manually with 'git add -f' to get around the .gitignore warning.

Comment: It's part of the git-extras suite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677121/is-there-an-ignore-command-for-git-like-there-is-for-svn, but you can also just add 'Debug' to .gitignore if you don't use that.